# unable to upload .aac file

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api, aac

I am recording an audio using `react-native-audio`, I am able to record and play the recorded file.

Issue is with sending .aac file to the api. Only for .aac file I am getting api error. If I try to record audio in any other format and send it to the api then its working. I am not sure why this is happening. If there was an issue with the api then other formats should also give some error. Below is my code:

```
const onSubmitPressed = async () => {
    const filePath2 = 'file://' + AudioUtils.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.aac';
    const fileSize = await getFileSizeInBytes(filePath2);
    console.log('fileSize: ',fileSize);
    uploadAACFile(filePath2);

  };
```

In here I am using `getFileSizeInBytes` to confirm that my file exists and have some size:

```
const getFileSizeInBytes = async (filePath1) => {
    try {
        const stats = await RNFS.stat(filePath);
        return stats.size;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error getting file size:', error);
        return -1;
    }
};
```

then finally:

```
const uploadAACFile = async (filePath1) => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('Id', '0');
      formData.append('EmployeeNo', '10003');
      formData.append('File', {
        uri: filePath1,
        type: 'audio/aac',
        name: 'test.aac',
      });
      

      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      };
      console.log('formData: ',JSON.stringify(formData));

      const response = await fetch('https://apiEndpoint', requestOptions);
      const result = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('File uploaded successfully');
        console.log('Response:', result);
      } else {
        console.log('File upload failed');
        console.log('Error:', result);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error:', error);
    }
  };
```

I am getting error:

`Error: {"Data": "", "ErrorMessage": null, "Message": "SaveFileInAzure", "NrOfRecords": 0, "Status": false}`

But if I try this with other formats like .lpcm then I am getting success response:

`Response: {"Data": "OK", "ErrorMessage": "", "Message": "OK", "NrOfRecords": 0, "Status": true};`

Comment: You need to check about this error with BE team, why this API fails specifically for aac file upload.